# Computed property names ({[a] : 1}) in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this code:

```
var r = {[ar[a]] : 1, [ar[b]] : 1, [ar[c]] : 1,[ar[d]] : 1, [ar[e]] : 1});
```

This works in Firefox but not in Chrome!

Does anybody know if there is a way around this without doing:

```
var r = {};
r[ar[a]] = 1;
r[ar[b]] = 1;
r[ar[c]] = 1;
r[ar[d]] = 1;
r[ar[e]] = 1;
```

This seems a little slow and messy. (And yes speed is very important here!)

Edit:
I used the extra [] around ar[a] because thats the way we do it in LUA, and it worked in firefox too :)

The full code is like this

```
var al = GC.length - 4;
var bl = al + 1;
var cl = bl + 1;
var dl = cl + 1;
var el = dl + 1;
var a,b,c,d,e;

var bc = [];
for (a = 0; a < al; a++)
    for (b = a+1; b < bl; b++)
        for (c = b+1; c < cl; c++)
            for (d = c+1; d < dl; d++)
                for (e = d+1; e < el; e++)
                    bc.push({[GC[a]] : 1, [GC[b]] : 1, [GC[c]] : 1,[GC[d]] : 1, [GC[e]] : 1});
```

Comment: What version of Firefox does that work in?  It doesn't work for me in Firefox 31.4.0 (ESR).

Comment: make array of variables and loop over them to create object?

Comment: Why are you doing `{[ar[a]] : 1}`?  Why do you have that extra `[]` around the key?  Do you want the key to be an array?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Computed property names?

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to implement [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) yet (it's an ES6 feature). Not much you can do about it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @FelixKling: I was mostly trying to figure out what he wanted the key to be.  If he wanted the key to be an array of one element or a scalar.

Comment: @FelixKling: Oh!  Is his example actually ES6 syntax?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Looks like it.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, you seem to be right: https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#enhanced-object-literals

Comment: *"This seems a little slow"* How did you test performance?

Comment: @pixie_frigo: There's your answer.  This syntax is ES6, which not all browsers support.

Comment: Slow for you? Or actually slower to run? Because I can't imagine it makes much difference when the code is actually running. If it's slow for you, just change your `a`, `b`, etc into an array so you can loop over it as @chartlietfl suggested. Something like `var indexes = [1,5,3,2,1];`

Comment: That's an interesting use case. What does this code actually do, maybe there's some way to optimize this - what does `bc` represent? How large is `GC.length` typically?

Comment: @bergi typical length of GC is 40-45. bc is used to do a quick lookup instead of iterating over GC.
So like this : if (!bc[cardNumber]) ...

Comment: @pixie_frigo: `bc[cardNumber]` is an object and never falsy. What are you doing with these objects? How do you use their properties?

Comment: @Bergie  Sorry I meant bc[i][cardNumber]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [computed property names](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals) have yet to land in latest Chrome (40.0.2214.115 at the time of writing), even though related features like [property name short-hand](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3584) are implemented under the Harmony flag.

Related bug report (star for updates): https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3754

Edit: Your first alternative is what I'd do in your stead, but since you said speed is critical the one thing you can do is benchmark. Not a micro benchmark of pitting both methods against each other without context, but benchmark your actual code in its several versions to see which one is optimised better.

Answer (score 1):

If speed is an actual problem here, I'd suggest to use a fixed-size array with the keys as items instead of variable-key object here:

```
var al = GC.length - 4, bl = al + 1, cl = bl + 1, dl = cl + 1, el = dl + 1;
var bc = [];
for (var a = 0; a < al; a++)
    for (var b = a+1; b < bl; b++)
        for (var c = b+1; c < cl; c++)
            for (var d = c+1; d < dl; d++)
                for (var e = d+1; e < el; e++)
                    bc.push([GC[a], GC[b], GC[c], GC[d], GC[e]]);
```

Then, to test for existence of a key use (instead of the `x in bc[i]` that you probably have somewhere):

```
function contains(tuple5, x) {
    "use strict";
    return tuple5[0]==x || tuple5[1]==x || tuple5[2]==x || tuple5[3]==x || tuple5[4]==x;
}
```

Comment: I'm intrigued by the 'use strict', I tried this code because I thought that 'use strict' would do something magical but ofcourse it's slower than just 
  
     if (bc[i][x])

Also I would use === instead of == ;) Not that it makes any noticeable difference :D But it should be faster in theory

Comment: hm, I though it might enable some optimisations. You could also try `tuple5.length = 5;` so that the property lookups are ensured to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have done the test and I was surprised of the outcome. I have coded a lot in LUA in the past. And declaring a new variable there eats a little out of the performance.

But apparently here its actually faster to do

```
var r = {};
r[GC[a]] = 1;
r[GC[b]] = 1;
r[GC[c]] = 1;
r[GC[d]] = 1;
r[GC[e]] = 1;
bc.push(r);
```

Probably because computed property names have to be ... computed ? ;) I don't know haha!
Thanks for the help !